What other goals could a space project with the primary goal of experience building with heavy lift rockets perform?
A nation is attempting to build a large scale manned space program. They are the primary pioneers in this world, and around the same stage as the US in the early-mid 1960s.
After getting a man in space, building a two person capsule and small space stations, and performing a lunar flyby, they create a comprehensive integrated plan for exploration of their inner solar system built around reusability, commonality, and development of permanent infrastructure. This is largely similar to our worlds Intergrated Program Plan from 1960. The two person capsule is similar to our world's Gemini and the station a blend of McDonnell's proposal for a Gemini derived space station and the USAF Manned Orbiting Laboratory, with the lunar flyby being different to any IRL plan for lunar Gemini (there were like 10 of them.)
The primary hardware planned for use with their integrated program for launch is a shuttle with a liquid fuel reusable flyback booster similar to the MSC-023 design although scaled up to a 60,000lb payload and a heavy lift system derived from it with a nuclear orbital transfer vehicle (initially a reusable heavy chemical orbital transfer vehicle is used instead) and space tug for moving payloads once in orbit.
The main problem for the purposes of the here is that there is a very large gap in scale between even the IRL MSC-023 design, let alone one scaled up for a 60,000lb instead of 40,000lb payload, and something like a Titan IIIM. This likely means an intermediate rocket would have to be developed. The problem then becomes, what can actually be done with this rocket that hasn't either already been done with the earlier missions like EVAs, station operations, and initial development for orbital assembly or overlaps with later efforts for missions launched on the Shuttle/Shuttle derived heavy lift combination of lunar landings, larger stations, and interplanetary flybys and landings.
So what could this rocket actually carry and purpose it serve beyond simply acting as an experience building exercise before construction of more complicated vehicles?
For reference the goals achived with the two man capsules are:

EVAs
Docking
Initial testing of winged space vehicles (Similar to winged Gemini),
Station operations
Basic orbital assembly
Lunar flyby

Missions reserved for more the more advanced systems are:

Larger truly modular stations
Lunar landing
Manned interplantary flybys, orbiters, and landings

The intermediate rocket would have a payload in the range of 35,000-60,000kg.

Are you mixing units? 60,000lb is 27,000kg, lower than your minimum bound for the intermediate rocket. Do you even need an intermediate rocket? The US with 60s tech went from Saturn IB with a payload of 21,000kg to Saturn V with a payload of 140,000kg (if I'm not mistaken, intermediate rockets were designed but never built).

In an alternate universe where the N-1 wasn't a disaster (because Korolyov didn't die or whatever), the Soviets also went from Proton-K with a payload of ~20,000kg to N-1 with 100,000kg.

@user111403 the 27,250kg payload vehicle is a shuttle so also has to lift a whole ass orbiter with the payload pushing up the total mass to orbit to more around the 100 tonne range. The thing is that they're not starting with a ~20 tonne payload rocket but a 13-17 tonne rocket and adding in the additional development complications of re usability.

“After getting a man in space”  Was it a requirement to be a man? Or could the culture in your story instead celebrate getting “a person” into space? That person may happen to be male in your story, but is that actually relevant?

@SRM i don't know i didn't think about the wording that much. but "man in space" is almost always the term used in the period irl so i kinda just defaulted to it

@SRM SE is a multicultural website with people from many English speaking backgrounds.  In middle English, "man" was a word that did not imply gender at all, you were "wer" if you were male, "wif" if you were female, and "man" if your gender was unspecified.  As language evolved, wif became wifman which became woman and man became a word that either did or did not imply a male gender depending on context as the use of wer fell out of use all together.

Many English speaking cultures still use "man" to mean either an the ungendered term for human or the male gendered human depending on context.  Given the context of the OP's writing style by saying things like "2 man capsules" it should be clear that they are from one of these English speaking traditions.

@SRM What I'm sure of is that we should be capable of choosing not to be offended by people who are not intentionally acting offensively concerning issues that have no relevance to the question.

@OT-64SKOT understood (though I still hate mixed units). My comment still stands. One country went from 20k to 140 and another tried. When they needed a super-heavy lifter, they made a super-heavy lifter, not an intermediate one. That's plausible with 60s tech. Reusability probably isn't. The first reusable launch vehicle was the SRB from the Shuttle, which flew in 1981, we didn't get another until a decade into the 21st century. Most likely they'll build a working super-heavy rocket launch vehicle first and develop reusability later.

@user111403 reusable super-heavy lift was a part of pretty much every plan for the shuttle before the final few TAOS designs. Maybe it's not feasible but until the budget people came and told them they had to cut development costs (well for like the 3rd or 4th time) a reusable superheavy first stage booster either a flyback one or a big pressure fed one were the leading option considered for Shuttle.

@jbh I wasn’t taking offense. Just noting that habits like that in our language cause recurring problems for women in our culture by continually reinforcing stereotypes. By noting it when it happens, we can start shifting our habits.

@OT-64SKOT well, that just proves the point, doesn't it? They'll build a rocket to do the job they need done. If they need an intermediate rocket, they'll build one. If they don't, they won't. If they really can't build the big one without the intermediate first, then that is your reason to build the intermediate. William Walker's answer is correct.

@user111403 I know that, as stated in the question that is the primary purpose. The issue is that it seems wasteful to launch perfectly good rockets and not actually put anything on top.

@OT-64SKOT Let me introduce you to Elon's Tesla Roadster. Wasteful, sure, but putting a multi-million dollar satellite on an experimental rocket with a high risk of exploding is also wasteful. If it's just a necessary intermediate step, it may only fly (successfully) once. If you feel you need more test flights and don't want to waste them, literally just stick in a couple extra satellites. I feel like you're overthinking this. You're not getting the answer you want because you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist.

@SRM My sisters, one of whom is a raging feminist, still use phrases like "manned space flight." I've never had a reason to ask, but considering they're successful career-holding artists and lawyers, I doubt the phrase has ever led them to cower under a stereotype (glass ceilings, on the other hand...). But more to the point, let's stick to building worlds and leave social justice home because we have users all across the world in many cultures and they deserve to have theirs just as you deserve to have yours.

@jbh Happy to discuss further in another forum. I see many flaws in your position. But I thank you for your civil reply.

The question answers itself.
Either the OP suffers from clarity of vision, wherein the R&D team in-universe doesn't actually know for certain that they will be able to build the final rocket in this evolution - else they'd cut directly to the chase; OR the use-case is self-evident to the R&D team and involves niche orbital requirements that are too expensive to transfer to out of standard practice orbits.
Technology doesn't improve incrementally because innovators/inventors are cautious by nature... because innovators/inventors are actually quite daring by nature.  Instead, it evolves incrementally because each step represents what the R&D team thinks is the new "best." The history of technology development is rife with examples of technologies that saw extremely limited windows of being used, because they were quickly surpassed.
If the R&D team believes an intermediate step is required, it's because they doubt their ability to go directly to the desired end product.  No further use case justification is required: the intermediate size system is part of the R&D costs of the final system rather than a standalone system designed for its own sake - essentially how fusion power is being developed IRL.
So if this intermediate proving step exists, it could indeed (if considered as a standalone system) seem to be a low, likely negative, ROI system, quickly replaced when its performance reveals that the payload ceiling is actually much higher than originally thought.
In which case, it may only ever fly once (or however many times are needed to prove the performance).
If it does fly again, or if it's NOT a required demonstrator stepping stone to the larger craft, then it's usefulness is a function of the Goldilocks principle: it's not too small, it's not too big - for certain payloads it's just the right amount of rocket.
Payloads too large to go on smaller vehicles, but needing to be burned directly into weird orbits (retrograde, Molinya, polar, etc.) that aren't compatible with being combined with other payloads to sufficiently fill the larger vehicle are good candidates for this - plane change maneuvers are expensive as hell and if you've got a good chunk of stuff you want on one of those weird orbits, it's cheaper to just burn directly into them.
Use-cases for these orbits:

Retrograde - See this answer on SX.SE Synthetic Aperture Radar benefits from the increased ground speed, sun-synchronous missions require these, opposite-coast launches use these for safety reasons.
Molinya - Highly inclined, eccentic orbits designed to get good loiter time over extreme latitudes - important for comms/gps/surveilance roles
Polar - Easy-button for ground imagery

Payload is fungible/commoditized, remember. So it's less about what missions might need that kind of payload, and more how much payload might need a particular burn profile. If you've got too much weird stuff for a smaller booster, but not enough to fill the big one, this vestigial holdover of a proving process turns out to be the perfect tool - dust it off and roll it to the pad.  These may not be large in number, but insofar as the gap between the smaller and larger sizes is deemed 'large' it is so because there's a need for something too big for the small, and too small/niche for the large - thus 'medium' is born.
These niche uses will involve characteristics of the ultimate orbit which are too expensive to transfer into from a traditional LEO or equivalent (and thus won't get combined with other payloads on a larger rocket because they're just not going the same direction).

The problem with this is that, as stated in the question, they are planning their future all in one go. They are specifically putting effort into long term large scale planning to redundant systems before they start work on this rocket. They very much do know what their future plans are as a whole and the initial proposal for this rocket is happening after they know what they want to do. The line of thinking stated in the question is the same one that leads to the system being developed in universe.

@OT-64SKOT Updated the answer - if they know they can achieve the end state, then they don't need the Size Medium launcher.  If they need the Size Medium launcher, it's for one of the given use cases.

But they do need the "medium" (still well into heavy lift) sized launcher to just have experience with one before trying to develop and even larger launcher with the added complication of reusability

@OT-64SKOT You say they do. I don't think they do. But if they think they do, then we're back to the first case: they don't realize they can just jump straight to the planned end point.  So the middle step is part of the R&D cost of that final product.

But why not stick something on it once they know it works ?

@OT-64SKOT Payload always comes first. The only thing they'd stick on it is something too big for the smaller system, but not going the same way as the larger system.  The reason for that is: If it's going the same way as other payloads, then payloads will be combined until they fill the largest available system (economy of scale). So, as I said in this answer, if they've got payloads going to weird orbits that don't fill the larger system, then yeah they'd stick something on it.  But you've established that they have a better system available for standard payloads.

But that system will only be ready after they know have to effectively utilize the intermediate one, because they want to have significant experience with large rockets before finalizing the design of their better one.

If the goal is making experience, you don't want to risk anything else in the process. Even in the very first launches you will use boilerplates rather than actual equipment, to reduce the losses related to a failure.
Nobody will want to risk destroying their equipment and the years of work and money behind it in a learning launch.
In the same way as a diamond cutter practices cutting potatoes before pitting their hands on a real one, you will do the same.

It seems wasteful to develop and gain significant experience with an entire heavy lift rocket then not use it for any actual payloads before ditching it for something else.

@OT-64SKOT you have funds to build more rockets, I have funds to make 1 object to send to space. First prove me you don't blow up, then I will put my money on your rocket.

I think your missing the point. The question isn't "what to put on an untested rocket", it's what to put on a rocket primarily made to provide practical experience to help develop another rocket after they know it works. Because otherwise they're putting a massive amount of effort into developing a rocket then never actually putting anything on a giant rocket they just put a massive amount of effort into developing and building production facilities for. It seems stupid to build a rocket, prove it works, then never use it again.

Multi-staged Rocket Platform & Boosters & Plans & Mistakes
Scalability - Technical Point of View
It is perfectly sane to build an intermediate sized rocket, even if they know they can scrap it afterwards.
The Titan IIIM you mentioned had 3 launches although there were many more scheduled (source). I am fairly sure those were just tests and not even real missions, because Wikipedia does not even list a single IIIM start.
If you want to have a more practical approach, then your scientists maybe had the bright idea to build a scaleable rocket platform with multiple stages. So they use stage 1+2 as intermediate size and later add a 3rd stage (could be a smaller on top, or a larger underneath stage 1) or swap stage 1+2 for bigger 1B+2B stages, which just have larger fuel tanks.
Alternatively/Additionally, they might have the idea of attaching Boosters, as the Space Shuttle had, to enable lifting more payload while using the same rocket platform.
This way they would have been able to plan ahead for various needs of payload capacities. But later were forced to skip many in-between steps and directly go for the scaled up MSC or the larger, heavy lifter system.
Scalability - Logical Point of View
It looks like a mix up between real and fictional facts.
(A) As I am aware, the MSC was only a concept, but was never realized. It was maybe the (direct) predecessor for what became the Space Shuttle program.
(B) You scaled that up in your story, which is fine.
(C) You detect a scaling problem in rocket sizes, which is true.
(D) Instead of fixing the scaling, you ask about more reasons to justify an intermediate rocket.
--> If they were able to build (or plan) a scaled up version of the MSC but this does not close the gap to the mightier heavy lifter (assuming the type Saturn here), then the initial scaling was not enough, I would argue. Alternatively, the scaling you intended was maybe to much to be plausible.
Meaning, they would have needed to scale even more to fill the gap/be plausible. At this point, the technical aspect of multi-staging the intermediate rocket comes into play.
Leveraging Miscalculations
Sure, they plan for the future, but any plan is revised, scrapped and reshaped multiple times before being even close to something to be realized. All the new lessons learned go into that plan, changing it constantly and shift things in ways nobody could ever been able to plan ahead for.
So maybe they do have miscalculated and already started producing the (intermediate, but in their eyes: heavy lifting) rocket before realizing their mistake of building it to weak.
Then they make the best of it and launch the already produced ones to gain experience, before starting the next project. At least this seems sensible because they are a "young spacefaring nation". Experience is everything in that stage. Especially in rocket science.
Motivation and Change of Plans
IRL we had the cold war and space race situation. This was the main motor for the whole space program. This also led to many decisions which left rockets intended for use going straight to the scrapyard or being salvaged, because the goals shifted and other priorities became more imminent.
So many things can go awry:

"we need to be faster"
"we must skip things because of budget which was not cleared"
"political situation changed unforeseeable"
"manufacturing flaws makes a produced rocket obsolete and a revision necessary"
"resources of material, man-power, unobtanium are short and we cannot resupply in time. We need to make sacrifices"
"our main rocket scientist died"
etc.

What happened was, the requirements on the goals to achieve changed (first). And therefore the requirements for the rockets needed,  changed as well.
Maybe you need to put more focus on the overall world-situation "happening" during your space program to tie more of those influential factors into it to explain things.
If you do not find more reasons to justify an intermediate rocket, that is okay! You can come up with so many reasons why this rocket was never built in large scale.
I know you want to find retrospective justifications because you, as the author know that there is a logical gap in the lifting capacity. But the reality of "human mistakes and changing plans" helps you far more here than brainstorming for more justifications for the rocket (those are part of the plot anyway and there you have all the power).


Launch a pair of spacecraft connected by a tether, spin for gravity.
This could be considered experience-building for interplanetary missions. In additon to your usual two-man craft, you will need the tether and and reel mechanisms, and engines to spin the whole assembly up. Perhaps this could have been launched with many little rockets, but it wasn't.

A station large enough to grow food in orbit.
Hydroponics might take more mass than your initial two-seaters, but fit into the proposed size range.

Put a nuclear power plant into space.
Either a radiothermal generator or a true reactor. The design might involve a mast for standoff distance and a shielding plate to protect the crew, in all larger than your first-gen rockets.



Space Race:
The basic module development and rockets get you into space. Shuttles are nice, long-term and complex projects that need to be developed later with advanced tech.
But what happens if there is another goal that MUST be met before you have the tech to build shuttles? You need a heavy-lifting rocket that can be built with relatively "simple" tech to get lots of mass into space.
Say you have a second apparently habitable planet in the solar system. Whoever gets there first with a human has a strong claim to it. Even if the other nations aren't as advanced, a collective effort by other states might threaten to challenge your primary.
Perhaps there is evidence of another civilization, or people even just THINK there was another on a nearby world. Imagine the leaps your space program could make with an alien spaceship to loot for tech (even if it's really just a funky asteroid looking like it was of intelligent design). This is before you have an endless stream of sophisticated probes, and you still need a person to do investigations in person. Build a ship in orbit now anf you may be able to skip the later steps...
Or perhaps there are incredibly valuable asteroids and much of the mineral wealth on the planet are elements only found as meteorites. You might even NEED these materials to continue the space program. These elements for example are critical for science and technology, and an abundant supply might be temptation enough to try and build a powerful space ship in orbit to retrieve some located a conveniently short distance away. Many rare-earth elements are involved in the production of nuclear power, and perhaps their vision for their next-gen spacecraft demands nuclear-powered ships, or to make scanners, displays, and powerful magnets.

this doesn't really answer the question it just creates an entirely different premise for the existence of the rocket

@OT-64SKOT The rocket is engineering. Why build an intermediate rocket calls for motive. You need a WHY that can't wait until the more advanced tech is ready.

They're building the intermediate rocket primarily just to gain experience with large rockets so they can build a larger and reusable one. The payload is just so they aren't launching empty rockets to know how it works.

@OT-64SKOT Your question. Without a compelling motive, expensive projects usually get cut until a short-term motive crops up, especially without competition.

i'm confused to exactly what you mean by this. There is a compelling motive, they need a learning step so they know how heavy lift rockets work before moving onto designing more complex systems. There isn't no precedent for this kind of thing either, see: Project Gemini.

@OT-64SKOT The US was willing to do this because of cold war competition. Each launch was a PR to the world. Your nation is apparently without real military or technological rivals. Eventually, enthusiasm will shift without external pressure, and people will ask why they're giving billions to aerospace conglomerates for no material gain while social issues, highways, or the police action in some backwater republic go unfunded.

There are political reasons for why they're putting so much effort into space that aren't reliant on them being in constant close competition with other powers that too long to stuff in the length of a stack exchange comment.

Those are some great questions about the intermediate rocket! I've been thinking about this a lot, and here are some ideas I came up with:
First off, we could use it for some really cool space station stuff. Like, bigger modules than before, maybe some specialized labs for microgravity experiments or manufacturing. We could test out prototype habitats for future moon or Mars bases too.
Fuel depots could be a big thing too. Launching huge fuel tanks to figure out orbital refueling would be super useful for later missions.
What about massive space telescopes? This rocket could put up some seriously big ones. We could test out the deployment systems for even bigger observatories down the line.
Also prototype landers. We could send up full-size (but unmanned) versions of lunar or planetary landers to test them out in Earth orbit.
Some other ideas:

Heavy cargo missions to show off our ability to move big payloads
Platforms for testing new propulsion tech like electric engines or solar sails
Large-scale manufacturing experiments in space (maybe even parts for solar power satellites?)
More complex orbital assembly practice
Big radiation shielding tests for future deep space missions
Artificial gravity experiments at a larger scale
Testing huge heat shields or reentry vehicles
Launching some badass Earth observation platforms

All this stuff would give us good experience with heavy lifting, push forward tech we need for later exploration, and keep people excited about the space program while we work on the really big projects. Plus, it'd bridge the gap between our earlier missions and the crazy ambitious stuff we want to do with the shuttle-derived systems.
Does anyone resonate with me here?
